# Sending email to multiple addresses in Python 3

Tags: python, smtplib

Recently we upgraded our Python from 2.x to 3.x. The commented out "brian@email.com" on line 11 will send an email, but the list of emails on line 10 discontinued functioning with going to 3.x. The error reported is " unhashable type: 'list'". How could I upgrade the multiple emails line to be compatible with Python 3.x?

```
fc = "D:\\WorkSpace\\Water\\Workspace.gdb\\NewAccountsGeocoded"
    fields = ['USER_MunisAccount','IN_Single_Line_Input']
    qry = "Status NOT IN ( 'M', 'T')"
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, qry) as cursor: 
        for row in cursor:
            print(row [0], row [1])           
            txtFile.write("{0}{1}".format(arcpy.GetMessages(), '\n'))
            HOST = "server.email.com"
            SUBJECT = "Report: Unable to Add UB Accounts to GIS Accounts"
            TO = ["symon@email.com","dave@email.com","brian@email.com"]
            #TO = "brian@email.com"               
            FROM = "Water Accounts<GIS@email.com>"
            text = "The following UB Account was not able to be imported into GIS WtrAccounts. Please see if there is an error in UB or if the address exists in COH Address GIS feature class. \n " + "UB Account: "+str(row[0]) + " | UB Address: "+str(row[1])+"\n"
            BODY = "From: {1}{0}To: {2}{0}Subject: {3}{0}{0}{4}".format('\r\n', FROM, TO, SUBJECT, text)
            server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST)
            server.sendmail(FROM, [TO], BODY)
            server.quit()
```

Comment: Since `TO` is already a list, why are you putting it into another list with `[TO]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python thinks you are trying to shape `TO` by using square brackets around it. In python you can simply call a list without the square brackets around it. You should only use the square brackets if you want a specific item in the list like `list[position_number]`. The second problem is the `TO` variable must be a string not a `list` even if there are multiple addresses they must just be separated by a comma

**The code:**

```
fc = "D:\\WorkSpace\\Water\\Workspace.gdb\\NewAccountsGeocoded"
    fields = ['USER_MunisAccount','IN_Single_Line_Input']
    qry = "Status NOT IN ( 'M', 'T')"
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, qry) as cursor: 
        for row in cursor:
            print(row [0], row [1])           
            txtFile.write("{0}{1}".format(arcpy.GetMessages(), '\n'))
            HOST = "server.email.com"
            SUBJECT = "Report: Unable to Add UB Accounts to GIS Accounts"
            TO = "symon@email.com, dave@email.com, brian@email.com"
            #TO = "brian@email.com"               
            FROM = "Water Accounts<GIS@email.com>"
            text = "The following UB Account was not able to be imported into GIS WtrAccounts. Please see if there is an error in UB or if the address exists in COH Address GIS feature class. \n " + "UB Account: "+str(row[0]) + " | UB Address: "+str(row[1])+"\n"
            BODY = "From: {1}{0}To: {2}{0}Subject: {3}{0}{0}{4}".format('\r\n', FROM, TO, SUBJECT, text)
            server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST)
            server.sendmail(FROM, TO, BODY)
            server.quit()
```

Comment: {('symon@email.com', 'dave@email.com', 'brian@email.com'): (501, b'5.1.3 Invalid address')}   - When I remove the brackets I received this error. I can verify that there are no typos in the real email addresses.

Comment: give me a second and ill fix it

Comment: I have fixed the isue, it needed to be a single string not a list

Comment: That did work, I just had to put double quotes around each email in the TO section.